# How come my binary number isn't properly converting to hexadecimal?

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

I am trying to convert a binary number to a hexadecimal number by converting the binary number to decimal first, then to hexadecimal.

When I run the part that converts decimal to hexadecimal alone, it works fine, but whenever I try to run both, it doesn't work?

```
for (returnBinary = length - 1; returnBinary > -1; returnBinary--) {

     if (input[returnBinary] == '1') {
        binDec = binDec + power(2, length - returnBinary - 1);
     }

}

// decimal to hex

while (binDec != 0) {

      remainder = binDec % 16;

       if (remainder < 10) {

         hexResult[returnBinary++] = 48 + remainder;

        } else {

         hexResult[returnBinary++] = 55 + remainder;

        }

        binDec = binDec / 16;

}

// print in reverse

printf("Your hexadecimal value is: 0x");

for (returnHex2 = returnHex; returnHex2 >= 0; returnHex2--) {
        printf("%c", hexResult[returnHex2 - 1]);
}
```

Each part works fine separately, but when put together it doesn't work.

EG: Converting the decimal number 60 to hex works fine, but when converting the binary equivalent of 60 (111100), it gives me a result of 0xC, when it should be 0x3C.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you are confusing the representation of a number with the value. You do not use any decimal representation in your code. `binDec` is not decimal in any way. An `int` only holds a value, neither decimal, nor hexadecimal or octal.

Comment: Besides the main problem with your index you could improve 2 things: Don't use magic numbers. Use `'0'` instead of `48` and `'A'-10` instead of `65`. You could also populate your array from right to left and don't need to print the result inverted.

Comment: @Gerhardh I hope you could also help me with this, but when I enter a large number to convert to hex, it prints out a bunch of gibberish (preceded by 0x). For example, 3245678765 converts to 0x-"(&#!+- when it should be 0xC17520AD. Any idea why?

Comment: With all the variable definitions missing it is hard to tell. You could add a complete example with any fixes to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing it through, I see that:

```
hex[-1] = 'C'
hex[0] = '3'
```

I suspect that you meant

```
hexResult[returnHex++] = 48 + remainder
```

instead of

```
hexResult[returnBinary++] = 48 + remainder
```

assuming that returnHex is initialized to zero.